# Proving $\alpha f + \beta g$ is measurable with respect to $\sum$ for all $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \sum)$ be a measurable space.

A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with respect to $\sum$ 
if

$\{x | f(x) < c \} \in \sum$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to show that the function $\alpha f + \beta g$ is measurable with respect to $\sum$ for all $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

I consider the case $\alpha, \beta =1$.

So I have the set $\{x | f(x) + g(x) < c\}
= (x | f(x) < c -g(x) \}$

This equals $\cup_{r_n} (\{x| f(x) < r_n \} \cap \{x| r_n < c-g(x) \})$

Where $r_n$ is the rational numbers.

Why is the union taken over the rationals? Why not irrationals or Reals?

How does this last step then show that the function $\alpha f + \beta g$ is measurable and why do we put $f(x) < r_n$ and $r_n < c-g(x)$?

Comment: Since  you can take a countable union by using rationals and a countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationals are countable. Measurable sets are closed under countable unions.

Comment: Why is putting $f(x) < r_n$ significant?

Comment: @Aljabra Notice that $f(x) < c - g(x)$ if and only if there is a rational number $r_n$ such that $f(x) < r_n < c - g(x)$. Thus the set $\{x | f(x) < c - g(x)\}$ is equal to the countable union in the text of your question.